# How to properly handle SIGINT with Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, sigint

I need to do some useful things when my [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/) service is stopped by `SIGINT`. Using Express.js version 3.0.6, I understand that this should work:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  console.log('Do something useful here.');
  server.close();
});
```

But the process doesn't give me back the Bash prompt unless I issue `SIGINT` (<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>) twice:

```
$ node problem.js 
^CDo something useful here.
^CDo something useful here.

net.js:1046
    throw new Error('Not running');
          ^
Error: Not running
    at Server.close (net.js:1046:11)
    at process.<anonymous> (/path/to/problem.js:8:10)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:93:17)
    at SignalWatcher.startup.processSignalHandlers.process.on.process.addListener.w.callback (node.js:486:45)
$
```

One more caveat. If I start this Express.js service *and don't send any requests* then `SIGINT` terminates properly.

Clearly there is something fundamental that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

By catching the `SIGINT` handler, you are preventing the *default behaviour*, which is to quit the process. When you use `Ctrl+C` the second time, the process dies because `server.close` throws an uncaught exception.

Just add a `process.exit()` to the end of your `SIGINT` handler to quit the process gracefully.

Comment: Using `process.exit()` is like sending a ^C after you did one thing and should not be considered gracefully (imho). I think a more complete answer is below (although a little late).

Comment: Instead of calling process.exit you should clear the event loop and set process.exitCode in case of an non successful exit.

Answer (score 18):

Resurrecting an oldie since the question is not completely (or correctly) answered and people might still find this answer.

The important part of your question is:

**One more caveat. If I start this Express.js service and don't send any requests then SIGINT terminates properly.
Clearly there is something fundamental that I'm missing here?`**

What you are missing is that by default express keeps connections open (HTTP keep-alive) for re-use. So, when there has been a (recent) request there's still something on the event-loop and that's the reason your app is not closing.

Using `process.exit()` will work, but is like sending another ^C, and may hide the fact that there is still something else open (e.g. database connections). Your app should just close when there's nothing left on the event-loop.

So, I modified your example, setting a 5 second keep-alive on the connection so it will graceful shutdown in a reasonable time.

```js
var express = require('express');

var serverPort = 3000;
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(serverPort);


// HTTP Keep-Alive to a short time to allow graceful shutdown
server.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.setTimeout(5 * 1000);
});

// Handle ^C
process.on('SIGINT', shutdown);

// Do graceful shutdown
function shutdown() {
  console.log('graceful shutdown express');
  server.close(function () {
    console.log('closed express');
  });
}

console.log('running server: http://localhost:' + serverPort);
```

Comment: Due to the long potential delay before shutdown, this may still not be ideal, and it makes keep-alive connections potentially less useful. For a more full solution, it might make sense to go for something like the graceful-exit module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-graceful-exit. That module will close keep-alive connections and wait for other activity to cease before exiting.

Comment: This bypasses the default behavior of control-c TWICE in a row. Probably should have a delay in there, waiting for the second press, and only then shutdown. What do you think?

Comment: The example above only illustrates what's going on with keep-alive on the connections. As @nneonneo mentioned, you should use an existing package to do this.

Answer (score 8):

I am using this code:

```
server.close(() => {
  process.exit(0)
})
```

Comment: Instead of calling process.exit you should clear the event loop and set process.exitCode in case of an non successful exit.

Comment: Agreed, this is better solution.